# No sound with the newest kernel version - is this a kernel bug or something else?

Tags: fedora, alsa

I have an external USB sound card on a Fedora 17 system (64 bit). It stopped playing sound after I updated the kernel to 3.5.4-1 (the problem persists under 3.5.4-2).

As the sound card still plays sound when I boot 3.5.3-1, I assume that the problem is neither hardware-related nor a matter of badly configured settings. I still checked the usual suspects for bad settings (Phonon, alsamixer, pavucontrol), but everything looks OK there as far as I can tell.

I assumed that this is a kernel bug, and even [submitted](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=861511) it. But now a friend sent me a link to a [Google Plus post](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+LinusTorvalds/posts/f51jR2JkGYk) which seems to say that a similar (the same?) problem is not a kernel bug, but comes from a kernel module not being loaded.

> it looks like the new alsa-utils or whatever now require SND_SEQUENCER

lsmod does not list SND_SEQUENCER on my system.

I don't know Linux well. In my understanding, if the problem is in alsa-utils, but only occurs with the new kernel, it means that either the new kernel is not loading a module the old one did load, or that booting with the new kernel also starts an old version of alsa-utils. Both explanation sound improbable to me, but I could be wrong.

My actual questions:

1. Could this really be a matter of the module not loading, despite the fact that alsa still works with the old kernel?
2. How do I get my system to load the module? (Do I have to install it first, and where does it come from?)
3. If this doesn't work, do you have other suggestions for trying to resove the problem (or at least determining for sure that it is indeed a kernel bug and so not resolvable with my limited knowledge)? I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `CONFIG_SND_SEQUENCER`.

The particular patch that caused this regression [has been found](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48051).
The fix [has been posted](https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/9/27/172) and should appear in some stable kernel eventually.